# MongoDB Field type

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to build a MongoDB that stores employee contact information, but the phone number field is giving me issues. For some reason it is showing up as a double type instead of an integer or string. This is what I have in my Class, although I have tried integer, string, and number to get the phone number correct

```
Class AllPhones
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

  field :name, type: String
  field :home, type: Integer
  field :cell, type: Number
  field :title, type: String
  field :workgroup, type: String

  index({name: 'text'})

end
```

This is what is displayed in RoboMongo:

```
home  5654455.0   Double
```

What is the best method to store phone numbers correctly in Mongo?

Thanks!!!

Comment: You should use String type to store phone numbers as they may contain non-numeric characters for formatting etc. You should also ensure that it is of type string before saving it to mongodb.

Comment: I did try that. I removed all records from the collection, updated the field type to String for both the home and cell fields and it still returns as a double.

Comment: How do you update the field type? You need to convert the passed in value to string e.g. change this 5654455.0 to 5654455.0 + "" so that it explicitly becomes a string

Comment: Thanks! I feel like silly now lol. That worked - as it should. Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

you can try using the same Number data type for :home field. It should most probably solve this issue. However, if it doesn't work you can try NumberInt() constructor to explicitly specify 32-bit integers. Try declaring the data type of :home by either ways mentioned below.

```
:home: Number
OR
:home:NumberInt
```

Comment: As suggested in the comments, phone numbers should be stored as strings. I'm not sure why you're answering a 4-year-old question with less-than-accurate answers.

Comment: I have tried and tested this on my on-going project. If you fire up MongoDB Shell in your system and run the command to store phone number with NumberInt() it will occupy 29 bit of memory on the other hand if you save it as a string it will occupy 33 bit memory in database. This way we can also optimize the database by keeping track of each data type and the memory it is consuming. While developing an app we must not forget about database optimization as it is also equally important.